# incomplate build

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using humble and moveit2 on ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.15.0-33-generic.

Terminal windows terminating it self while colcon building.

Details;
GPU:
`nvidia-smi`

```
Fri May 27 14:38:08 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.73.05    Driver Version: 510.73.05    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P1000        Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   55C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      5MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1851      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2143      G   ...ome-remote-desktop-daemon        0MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0

stdout.log is:

```
[  1%] [34m[1mAutomatic MOC for target moveit_rviz_plugin_render_tools[0m
[  1%] Built target moveit_rviz_plugin_render_tools_autogen
[ 18%] Built target moveit_rviz_plugin_render_tools
[ 20%] [34m[1mAutomatic MOC for target moveit_planning_scene_rviz_plugin_core[0m
[ 22%] [34m[1mAutomatic MOC for target moveit_robot_state_rviz_plugin_core[0m
[ 22%] Built target moveit_robot_state_rviz_plugin_core_autogen
[ 22%] Built target moveit_planning_scene_rviz_plugin_core_autogen
[ 27%] Built target moveit_robot_state_rviz_plugin_core
[ 34%] Built target moveit_planning_scene_rviz_plugin_core
[ 36%] [34m[1mAutomatic MOC for target moveit_robot_state_rviz_plugin[0m
[ 39%] [34m[1mAutomatic MOC for target moveit_trajectory_rviz_plugin_core[0m
[ 39%] [34m[1mAutomatic MOC for target moveit_planning_scene_rviz_plugin[0m
[ 39%] Built target moveit_robot_state_rviz_plugin_autogen
[ 39%] Built target moveit_planning_scene_rviz_plugin_autogen
[ 39%] Built target moveit_trajectory_rviz_plugin_core_autogen
[ 44%] Built target moveit_robot_state_rviz_plugin
[ 50%] Built target moveit_trajectory_rviz_plugin_core
[ 55%] Built target moveit_planning_scene_rviz_plugin
[ 56%] [34m[1mAutomatic MOC for target moveit_trajectory_rviz_plugin[0m
[ 58%] [34m[1mAutomatic MOC for target moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core[0m
[ 58%] Built target moveit_trajectory_rviz_plugin_autogen
[ 58%] Built target moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core_autogen
[ 63%] Built target moveit_trajectory_rviz_plugin
[35m[1mConsolidate compiler generated dependencies of target moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core[0m
[ 65%] [32mBuilding CXX object motion_planning_rviz_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core.dir/moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o[0m
[ 67%] [32mBuilding CXX object motion_planning_rviz_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core.dir/src/motion_planning_frame.cpp.o[0m
[ 68%] [32mBuilding CXX object motion_planning_rviz_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core.dir/src/motion_planning_frame_context.cpp.o[0m
[ 70%] [32mBuilding CXX object motion_planning_rviz_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core.dir/src/motion_planning_frame_planning.cpp.o[0m
[ 72%] [32mBuilding CXX object motion_planning_rviz_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core.dir/src/motion_planning_frame_objects.cpp.o[0m
[ 74%] [32mBuilding CXX object motion_planning_rviz_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core.dir/src/motion_planning_frame_scenes.cpp.o[0m
[ 75%] [32mBuilding CXX object motion_planning_rviz_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core.dir/src/motion_planning_frame_states.cpp.o[0m
[ 77%] [32mBuilding CXX object motion_planning_rviz_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core.dir/src/motion_planning_frame_joints_widget.cpp.o[0m
[ 79%] [32mBuilding CXX object motion_planning_rviz_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core.dir/src/motion_planning_display.cpp.o[0m
[ 81%] [32mBuilding CXX object motion_planning_rviz_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core.dir/src/motion_planning_frame_manipulation.cpp.o[0m
```

Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401463/incomplate-build/) by [aGan](https://answers.ros.org/users/106181/agan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I change swapfile size 2gb to 16gb and able to build with

```
colcon build --mixin debug --parallel-workers 2
```

---

Originally posted by [aGan](https://answers.ros.org/users/106181/agan/) with karma: 16 on 2022-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0